# Best way to keep track of counter at database level

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I want to keep track of a user **counter** though time and be able to generate stats about the **changes** in the counter through time.

I'm pretty set (although if they are better ways I would like to hear about them) about the two main tables. user and counter_change that would look pretty much like this:

```
user:
+-----------+------------+
| id        | username   |
+-----------+------------+
| 1         | foo        |
| 2         | bar        |
+-----------+------------+
counter_change:
+-----------+--------------------+------------+
| user_id   | counter_change_val | epoch_time |
+-----------+--------------------+------------+
| 1         | 10                 | 1513242884 |
| 1         | -1                 | 1513242889 |
+-----------+--------------------+------------+
```

I want to be able to show the **current counter** value (with the base value being 0) at the frontend as well as some stats trough time (ex: yesterday your net counter was +10 or -2, etc)

I've thought about some possible solutions but none of them seem to be the *perfect* solution.

### Add counter to `user` table (or on some new `counters` table):

This solution seems to be the more resources effective, at the time of inserting a counter_change, update the counter in `user` with the counter_change_val.

### Pros:

Get the counter current value would consume virtually no resources.

### Cons:

The sum of counter_changes_val could diverge from the counter in `user` if a bug occurs.

Couldn't be really used for stats fields as it would require an additional query, and at that point a trigger would be more handy.

---

### Add a *calculated* counter to `user` table (or on some new `counters` table) on insert/update:

This solution would consist of a SQL trigger or some sort of function at ORM level that would update the value on an insert to the the counter_change table with the sum of the counter_change_val.

This would be also used on calculated fields that imply grouping by dates. For example get the average daily changes of the last 30 days.

### Pros:

Get the counter current value would consume virtually no resources.

### Cons:

On every insert an aggregation of all the current user `counter_change` would be needed.

---

### Add a view or select with the sum of counter

This solution would consist of creating a view or select to get the sum of the aggregate counter_change_val when needed.

### Pros:

Adds no fields to the tables.

### Cons:

As it is calculated at runtime it would add time to request response time.
Every time the counter is consulted an aggregation of the counter_change values would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I am not sure that I have understood what you are trying to do. Nevertheless, I would suggest Option 1 or Option 2:

Option 1 is efficient, and it is sufficiently safe against errors if it is done right. For example, you could wrap inserting the counter_change and computing the new counter_value in a transaction; this will prevent any inconsistencies. You could do that either in the back-end software or in a trigger (e.g. upon inserting a counter_change).

Regarding Option 2, it is not clear to me why an aggregation over all the counter_change of the current user would be needed. You can adjust the counter_value in the user table from within an insert trigger as with option 1, and you can use transactions to make it safe.

IMHO, adjusting the current counter_value upon every insert of a counter_change is the most efficient solution. You can do it either in the back-end software or from within a trigger. In both cases, use transactions.

Option 3) should not be used because it will put much of load onto the system (assume you have 1000 counter_changes per user ...).

Regarding the statistics: This is a different problem from storing the data in the first place. You probably will need some sort of aggregation for any statistical data. To speed this up, you could think about caching results and things like that.

Comment: Option 2 would be more oriented to stats fileds, the ones that need a time range. I should had specified that in the question. Also, what are you not sure of understanding?